# Are the winter map files still accessible?

Tags: league-of-legends

Maybe some of you guys remember the [winter map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXVLh.jpg) from league of legends that was released in 2012 or 2011 (and earlier, but that was an older model). Now I remember searching for special files when it was somehow easier to view the content of the game (around 2011) and I also found some Icons of Items that already didn't exist anymore at this point like zhonyas ring or the blue pill.

Now since there are (or were) files of things that don't exist anymore, I thought about whether the new or old winter/halloween maps are still in the game files or not. And if they are, how could you activate them as the default map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This map has not been updated in some time. So even if the files did still exist in the downloaded content on your machine, and you were able to activate it somehow, most likely it would cause errors during play.

Many walls, brushes, etc are different between the last released winter map and the current season map. I'm not sure exactly how league servers would deal with this, but most likely you'd be clipping inside walls as your computer would fight against the server to determine what is correct. At best you will have issues navigating the map and determining bushes, etc; at worst you won't be able to play at all until you revert the change.

That being said, I'm not familiar with a method to change the default map, and Riot (at the present time) does not support such modification of your client. AND the map would only be available for you if you were able to get it to work, not your teammates or opponents.

Comment: While this isn't the answer you are looking for, hopefully this is still a useful answer to outline the risks involved in doing this. If you find a way to do this, please try it out in a custom game first.

Comment: Well damn that's true... I completely forgot about the bushes and so on... Still thanks alot^^